# Objects with gravity fall continuously before Image Target renders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to render some content onto an Image Target and one of the objects has a `Rigidbody` with gravity. The object with gravity starts to fall as soon as the scene starts, but the image target has not been recognized yet so it keeps falling forever.

I saw some code online suggesting to implement `ITrackableEventHandler` but the [guide](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-Vuforia-and-Unity.html) on Vuforia's site doesn't work anymore.

The code Vuforia suggests is below:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;
public class MyPrefabInstantiator : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {
  private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
  public Transform myModelPrefab;
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start ()
  {
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour) {
      mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
  }
  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update ()
  {
  }
  public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
  { 
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
      OnTrackingFound();
    }
  } 
  private void OnTrackingFound()
  {
    if (myModelPrefab != null)
    {
      Transform myModelTrf = GameObject.Instantiate(myModelPrefab) as Transform;
      myModelTrf.parent = mTrackableBehaviour.transform;
      myModelTrf.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
      myModelTrf.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
      myModelTrf.localScale = new Vector3(0.0005f, 0.0005f, 0.0005f);
      myModelTrf.gameObject.active = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia has implemented `ITrackableEventHandler` for you with the class `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`

You can enable and disable gravity with a script like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class EnablePlayerGravity : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{
    public Rigidbody player;

    override protected void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        player.useGravity = false;
    }
    override protected void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        player.useGravity = true;
    }
}
```

You don't need to register this with the `ImageTarget`'s `TrackableBehavior` because the `Start` method of `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` already does that for you. All you need to do is drop this script onto your `ImageTarget` and then set the player's (or whichever object has gravity) Rigidbody in the inspector.